# How can sed replace in the range of nth line regex specified?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, gnu

I am to replace using sed the 3th (or nth to be more general) occurrence in respective line with specified match regex.
so far as i can is only to do the first:

```
$cat file   
# Golden dictionary is a versatile multi purpose reference  
# Copyright (C) 2004-2008 A  
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015 B  
# Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C
```

so far as i can is only

```
$ cat file| sed -E '0,/copy/I s//No-&/'

# Golden dictionary is a versatile multi purpose reference  
# No-Copyright (C) 2004-2008 A  
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015 B  
# Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C
```

How to do so by such way for the 3th match only?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You want the third *line* that contains the text to be prefixed with `No-`? Or the third occurrence no matter where it is?

Comment: the third occurrence of respective line, no matter to many occurrences in a line, if 2nd line is # Copyright (C) 2004-2008 Copyright (C) 2009 Copyright (C) 2018 # Copyright (C) 2019 A   ,still must find 4th line Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C to be replace then

Answer (score 1):

With ed, prefixing the 3rd case-insensitive "copy" with "No-" would be:

```
ed -s file <<< $'/[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy]/\n//\n//\ns//No-&/\nw\nq' > /dev/null
```

The commands are:

- `/[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy]/` -- search, in a manually case-insensitive way for "copy:
- `//` -- repeat the search, twice
- `s//No-&/` -- replace the last match with the "No-" prefix
- `w` -- write the change file to disk
- `q` -- quit ed

With sed, you could do some pre-work to find the line number to change:

```
sed -i $(grep -in copy file |awk -F: 'NR==3 { print $1 }')'s/copy/No-&/i' input
```

Working from left to right,

- `-i` -- GNU sed's in-place edit option
- `$( ... )` -- find the line number of the 3rd match of "copy"

  - `grep -in copy file` -- find the word "copy", case-insensitively in `file` and report the line numbers of the matches
  - `awk -F: 'NR==3 { print $1 }'` -- on line 3 of grep's output, split the line on colons and report back column 1 (the line number)
- `s/copy/No-&/i` -- replace "copy" with "No-copy", case-insensitively

Comment: Or newish gawk could do the change itself: `awk -i inplace -vIGNORECASE=1 '/copy/&&++n==3 {sub(/copy/,"No-&")} 1' file` (for other awk you could do `[Cc]` etc and the `awk ... file >temp && mv temp file` dance)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, counting how many lines contain the string `Copyright`, and when we reach the third such line, perform a substitution of the first such occurrence on that line:

```
awk '/Copyright/ && ++n == 3 { sub("Copyright", "No-&") } { print }' file
```

Using `&` in the replacement means using whatever the regular expression matched.  In this case it will be the string `Copyright` that will be inserted.  This (using `&`) also works in e.g. `sed`.

The condition before the first block,

```
/Copyright/ && ++n == 3
```

would match the string `Copyright` against the current line. If it matches, `n` would be incremented.  If the incremented value of `n` is equal to 3, the block is executed.

Testing:

```
$ cat file
# Golden dictionary is a versatile multi purpose reference
# Copyright (C) 2004-2008 A
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015 B
# Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C
# Golden dictionary is a versatile multi purpose reference
# Copyright (C) 2004-2008 A
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015 B
# Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C
```

(the file is the same as yours, but with the contents duplicated once)

```
$ awk '/Copyright/ && ++n == 3 { sub("Copyright", "No-&") } { print }' file
# Golden dictionary is a versatile multi purpose reference
# Copyright (C) 2004-2008 A
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015 B
# No-Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C
# Golden dictionary is a versatile multi purpose reference
# Copyright (C) 2004-2008 A
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015 B
# Copyright (C) 2015-2016 C
```